# Getting language prefix as parameter from Angular 6 router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular (6.0.3) application and I want to use the language as a common prefix to all routes, something like `/en/foo/bar`.  My  route definition `src/app/submodule/submodule.routes.ts` looks like this:

```
export const submoduleRoutes = [
    { path: ':lingua/foo/bar', component: FooBarComponent },
];
```

My root component `src/app/app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'app';
  private sub: any;


  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

When I navigate to `/xy/foo/bar`, the `FooBarComponent` gets rendered. But I  am not able to retrieve language prefix in the root component. The `params`  hash is empty.

The console output first displays `{}` for the empty params, and then the `NavigationEnd` event.

The same code works as expected in the `FooBarComponent`. Obviously, the root component is the wrong place to get the parameters.

My goal is actually to get the `lingua` parameter for all components, so that I can set the correct language. I know that I could  also store the language in a cookie or local storage but I need bookmarkable URLs for the multi-lingual content.

In case that matters, the source code is at https://github.com/gflohr/Lingua-Poly (commit 12608dc). The route in question is defined in https://github.com/gflohr/Lingua-Poly/blob/master/src/app/main/main.routes.ts (at the end,  `:lingua/mytest`.

Comment: I could, of course, manually parse the language prefix out of the URL inside the handler for the `NavigationEnd` event but that smells hacky to me.

Comment: If you want the `lingua` param in AppComponent, you should give it is own route (with the `lingua` parameter), and make everything else a child route

Comment: @user184994 As far as I understand, the route is already a child route. But I could be wrong. I have updated the question with a link to the  source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make them children of the `App.component` for it to work.

For example:

```
const routes = [
  { path: ":lingua", component: AppComponent, loadChildren: 'app/main/main.module#MainModule' },
  { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "/en" }
]
```

This will load all the child routes from main module, but allow `AppComponent` to access the `lingua` parameter.

You will then need to remove the `:lingua` part from your child route

**[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btyop6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**

Comment: I have commited that change ([master c1da314]) but it  doesn't work for me. The `params` are still  empty in  `app/app.component.ts`.

Comment: You need to remove `:lingua` from your child route, otherwise it will need to be on the path twice

Comment: When I remove it, I get a compile-time error: Could not resolve module app/main/main.module relative to /path/tol/Lingua-Poly/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Change it to `loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule'`

Comment: Having just tried this locally, you may want to create a new component that contains nothing but a `router-outlet`, and use that as the parent instead of `AppComponent`

Comment: It took me some time to get back to this but it's working now like you suggested with a couple of minor modifications for Angular 9.